# VSCode Intellisense for Laravel Realtime Facades

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, laravel-facade

When using realtime facades in Laravel, VSCode doesn't seems to provide intellisense or autocompletion. Even when using popular plugins like PHP Intelliphense I can't get it to work. However, when I import the class normally it works just fine.

For example, this has no intellisense/autocompletion features:

```
use Facades\App\User;
User::auth();
```

But this does:

```
use App\User;
User::auth();
```

I feel like this has to be a common problem since Facades are a core concept in Laravel. Does anyone know a workaround or solution to this problem?

Comment: It's lack of support for @mixin. There is an equivalent issue in [vscode-intelephense](https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues/123). Unfortunately also not yet fixed

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to give this package a try:

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

It fixes the facades problem for you visual studio, as they say in the package description:

> This package generates helper files that enable your IDE to provide accurate autocompletion. Generation is done based on the files in your project, so they are always up-to-date.

Comment: It's worth noting that there's a VS Code extension called `Laravel Ide Helper` that runs `laravel-ide-helper` commands on `*.php` file saves to keep things up-to-date.